# Changing Eclipse CDT setting's tab background colour

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How do I change the background colour of the active tab in Eclipse CDT's preferences/properties pages? I'm on the dark theme and the white words are clashing with the white background and I am unable to find the right place to change it in under Preference > General > Appearance > Colors and Font.

Screenshot:

[image: Setting's tab colour]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're not using an outdated version? If it also occurs in Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9), report it to Eclipse (assuming nobody has reported it already).

Comment: Yup, this is occurring on the latest Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).

Comment: On Linux with GTK 3.14+ you can use the `GTK_THEME` environment variable as a workaround for this bug: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#gtk3-theme-override-support